# Magento2 interface not found in Model class

Tags: magento2, error, payment-methods, model, interface

I am new to Magento2. I am developing a payment method and I am getting the  message:

> **Fatal error**:  Interface 'Test\TestThesis\Model\Test\TestThesis\Api\Data\CryptocurrencyInterface' not found in **C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Test\TestThesis\Model\Cryptocurrency.php** on line **9**

I have added the dependency in `di.xml`. Is there something that I am missing and I am getting this message?

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestThesis\Model;


use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;


class Cryptocurrency extends AbstractModel implements Test\TestThesis\Api\Data\CryptocurrencyInterface 
{

    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init('Test\TestThesis\Model\ResourceModel\Cryptocurrency');
    }

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @see CryptocurrencyInterface
     */
    public function getId(){
        return $this->getData(self::ENTITY_ID);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $id
     * @return type
     * @see CryptocurrencyInterface
     */
    public function setId($id){
        return $this->setData(self::ENTITY_ID, $id);
    }
```

And the interface:

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestThesis\Api\Data;

/**
 * Interface CryptocurrencyInterface
 *
 * @package Test\TestThesis\Api\Data 
*/
interface CryptocurrencyInterface
{

    const ENTITY_ID = 'id';
    const ORDER_ID = 'order_id';
    const AMOUNT_DEPOSIT = 'amount_deposit';
    const STATUS = 'status';

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId();

    /**
     * @param $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function setId($id);
```

Comment: I will be working on a while on magento 2 v2.3.4. Suddenly my admin panel is not working and shows the below error. Please help Interface 'Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\DataTypeInterface' not found in D:\xampp7.3.31\htdocs\magento2-2.3.4\magento2-2.3.4\app\code\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\AbstractDataType.php on line 16

Answer (score 1):

If you have already added the dependency in `di.xml`, then change `Test\TestThesis\Api\Data\CryptocurrencyInterface` to `\Test\TestThesis\Api\Data\CryptocurrencyInterface` and try again.

Comment: no luck... do I miss a class that should interact with the model? maybe a helper? i dont know

Comment: run setup:upgrade and flush the cache and try again. Also, share the di.xml code.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Test\TestThesis\Api\Data\CryptocurrencyInterface" type="Test\TestThesis\Model\Cryptocurrency" />
</config>

Answer (score 0):

You have obviously mistaken in the namespace of the implemented interface (prseumably in `di.xml` preference node):

> Fatal error: Interface
>   '**Test\TestThesis\Model\Test\TestThesis\Api\Data**\CryptocurrencyInterface'
>   not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Test\TestThesis\Model\Cryptocurrency.php
>   on line 9

The answer is almost ALWAYS in the Error message: the path can't be `Test\TestThesis\Model\Test\TestThesis\Api...`

I often did some mistakes in the namespaces so I understand how it annoys ;D

Hope this will help!